# Postgres : Select the maximum integer substring of a column value

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, substring

I'm using postgresql and I'm having a trouble formulating the right sql query. The title of the question might sound weird, but it is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'm currently performing data curation with a particular table. If I have a table **product** containing :

```
id | designation
---------------------
1  | IR15A1021
2  | IR15A1001
3  | IR15A1050
4  | AB100 
5  | AR100
```

**What I want to do is to:**

1) Get the integer substring of **only** and **exactly** those records with the designation **whose pattern starts with 'IR15A'**. And by integer substring, meaning the number after the starting string 'IR15A'. (1021,1001,1050)

2) Get the maximum integer substring so in this case :

```
maximum integer substring : 1050
```

Because all other IR15A have max substrings less than it (1021 and 1001).

**Assume correct conditions.**

1) Substring after the IR15A is ALWAYS integer so no worrying about the type, it will be always integer.
2) Ignore other designation patterns. just the IR15A.

I've only managed to get the '%IR15A%' wildcard search but I haven't found any solution to cut the integer substring out of it and compare it with others to get the maximum. Thanks!

Comment: Are there always 4 digits after IR15A ? Or may it vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(cast(substring(designation from '....$') as int))
from tab
where designation like 'IR15A%'
```

1. Take only rows with `IR15A` using `like 'IR15A%'`
2. Remove `IR15A` using `substring(designation from '....$')`.
3. Convert it to int using `cast`
4. Take `max` value using `max()`

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b19e/6/0) demo**

Comment: wow! just tested this right away and it worked like a charm. Follow up, how did you manage to install postgres in your brain? xD i'll be accepting this answer within a few minutes. thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this only works if the pattern has 4 digits after `IR15A`, in which case you should be using `right(designation, 4)` instead of `substring` since your pattern match is unnecessary. Otherwise use a regular expression pattern match with a greedy qualifier. +1 anyway because you actually explained your answer, though not its limitations.

Comment: Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b19e/12 . It's made a bit more awkward by the fact that `regexp_matches` returns an array.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you for comment! You are right, my solution is not universal is prepared for this case. OP said `2) Ignore other designation patterns. just the IR15A.`